# как сделать чтоб в python socket клиент сделал скриншот и отправялл его на сервер

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, клиент-сервер, client

Как можно сделать скриншот клиента и передать его на сервер? Я сначала подумал что это будет легкая задача но столкнулся с проблемой как можно выполнить команду для скриншота вить если просто передать команду то она не исполниться а просто сохраниться и все

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вам нужен:
1. Серверная часть, которая принимает запросы от клиентов
2. Клиент, который может подключиться к серверу и передать скриншот экрана
3. Сервер может попросить клиента сделать скриншот ?

Comment: Да вы все правильно поняли

Comment: Серверная и клиентская части есть туты: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223223/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-python/1223283?noredirect=1#comment2140991_1223283

Comment: Вот пример скриншота: http://python-3.ru/page/sozdanie-screenshot-python

Comment: Вам остаётся только объединить клиент с кодом скриншота и отправить картинку на сервак

Comment: Вот тут есть вариант отправки файла с клиента на сервак: https://coderoad.ru/9382045/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-Python

Comment: а на какой ОС должен быть запущен клиент(Linux, Windows или MacOS)?

Comment: на операционной системе Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**server.py** - простой TCP сервер, который принимает любое сообщение за файл. После записи файла проверяется его настоящий mime-type. Нужно это для совместимости в виндовсом, ибо виндовс не хочет открывать файл без расширения в отличие от могучого Линукса. После происходит rename файла с добавлением его mime-type. Можно указать на каком IP адресе запустить сервер. (0.0.0.0 нужен, чтобы могли подключиться к этому серверу хосты с разных сетей. localhost - только с этого компютера). Также можна указать каталог, в который сохранять приходящие файлы.

```
import socket
from os.path import expanduser
import os
import magic


class Server:

    def __init__(self, address='localhost', port=8080, save_dir=expanduser('~')):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((address, port))
        self.file_id = 1
        self.save_dir = save_dir
        self.address = address
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        self.socket.listen(1)
        while True:
            client_socket, client_address = self.socket.accept()
            file_path = os.path.join(self.save_dir, str(self.file_id))
            file = open(file_path, 'wb')
            while 1:
                data = client_socket.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    file.write(data)
                else:
                    break
            mime = magic.from_file(file_path, mime=True).split('/')[1]
            os.rename(file_path, file_path + '.' + mime)
            self.file_id = self.file_id + 1
            file.close()
            client_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
    server.run()
```

**client.py** - простой TCP клиент, который принимает файл и отправляет его TCP серверу. Также содержит логику, чтобы сделать скриншот с помощью библиотеки PIL

```
from os.path import expanduser
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket
import os


class Client:

    def __init__(self, host_address='localhost', host_port=8080):
        self.socket = socket.socket()
        self.host_address = host_address
        self.host_port = host_port
        self.socket.connect((host_address, host_port))

    def send_file(self, file_name):
        file = open(file_name, 'rb')
        self.socket.sendfile(file)


def screenshot(to_file, mime='JPEG'):
    _screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    _screenshot.save(to_file, mime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = os.path.join(expanduser('~'), '30.jpeg')
    screenshot(file_name)
    cli = Client()
    cli.send_file(file_name)
```

Запуск происходит двух файлов по отдельности. Сначала сервер, потом клиент. Каждый раз, когда хотите загрузить скриншот компютера, нужно запустить client.py
Кажется, вам не придеться даже устанавливать сторонние зависимости и кажется, что он кросс-платформенный(проверено только на Ubuntu 20.04)